# How to enqueue a random css style?

Tags: css, wp-enqueue-style

I want a random CSS style file to load on my site with each page view so I can play with colors backgrounds.

So I put all my styles in a folder, I named them `1.css`, `2.css`, etc. and I have added:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='name-random-color-css' href='http://www.url.com/wp-content/themes/themename/inc/rcolor/<?php echo mt_rand(1, 9) ?>.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

in the header.

It works but I know this is not the proper way to include styles in WordPress. I should utilize the `wp_enqueue_style` function in the `functions.php` file, but I don't know how to combine the two to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work!

```
function enqueue_random_style() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-name', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/inc/rcolor/' . mt_rand(1, 9));
}    
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_random_style' );
```